# Abstracting MassTransit into a class library

Tags: masstransit

I have a class library project that will contain all the MassTransit configurations, IBusControl, DTOs, queue and exchange configurations. However, the consumer classes need to be in the projects that will be responsible for consuming the published messages. At the same time, these consumer classes need to be added to the IBusControl, but as I mentioned, they are in worker service and web projects. How do I add the consumers from these projects to the class library project? All projects reference the class library, and it would be redundant to reference the projects in the class library. I haven't found a way to do this.

```cs
public class RabbitMQBusFactory
    {
        public static IBusControl CreateBus(string rabbitMQUrl, string rabbitMQUser, string rabbitMQPassword)
        {
            var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitMQUrl), hostConfig =>
                {
                    hostConfig.Username(rabbitMQUser);
                    hostConfig.Password(rabbitMQPassword);
                });

                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(host);
            });

            return busControl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Chris, I'm new to StackOverflow. Thank you for correcting my question. Do you know how to help me? I have this IBusControl configuration in a class library, but consumers will be in other projects. I don't want to repeat too much code. How can I have consumers in other projects and the MassTransit configuration abstracted in a class library?

Comment: I'm keen to try and do this for my request/response services that are shared across multilple solutions/APIs. Essentially I was thinking of being able to do something like services.AddMyService() which also does the  x.AddRequestClient<ISomeQueryInterface>() but I don't know how to do this after services.AddMassTransit has been called!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar setup and here's what I've accomplished.

I have specific projects for each message bus domain (consumers/producers/config/records/etc.) and use those in the targeted web or service project. A 'domain' being a grouped/related set of system functionality . When configuring any consuming application to use these projects I simply use the configuration extensions from that referenced project during its own configuration initialization. There are specifics I also handle in the main application for configuration only, but all executing code for handling the publishing/sending/consumption of messages is all contained within the subproject. The publishing/sending calls are in the consuming application as that is driving the event/command sequence so there are links into these subprojects within the application's code. However, those are interfaced and DI'd to the call sites, nothing MassTransit specific is in the call chain of publishes/sends.

If there are application specific consumers, let's say SignalR hub calls, those can only exist for the scope of that service. So all SignalR consumers responding to the bus only exist in that scope's, i.e. the Web application, code base. Those need to be added in that app's configuration as well, but again, use extensions in that layer/application.

I am running a web application that submits to the message bus for various tasks, and any number of services that run against the bus to process them. When there is no proper backend the web app runs all consumers in memory so there is no effective difference in operation, this is a configuration choice for development purposes. When a proper backend is configured, the web application doesn't attempt to load all consumers and goes about its business, letting the expected services process messages.